# Get all possible matches in regex

Tags: php, regex

For example I have the following string:

```
(hello(world)) program
```

I'd like to extract the following parts from the string:

```
(hello(world))
(world)
```

I have been trying the expression `(\((.*)\))` but I only get `(hello(world))`.

How can I achieve this using a regular expression

Comment: I would advise against using regex for this. It is not useful for irregular languages, especially when nesting is involved.

Comment: I would advise that you ignore the above (@VasiliSyrakis) because we don't know enough to say "this is a LISP like dialect!". Recursion (PERL REGEX FTW (not perl itself!)) would allow this, he may also want the inner most match, so `?:` might be useful. Or a not-greedy match, there's not enough info to work out what he wants.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis Hmm.me being a newbie, could you give a brief explanation as to why regex isn't the best option?

Comment: @JeyachandranRathnam have a look at the documentation link in Amal's answer; it has some good information on this exact problem.

Comment: Well, the `?R` token is new to me. More to study then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression might not be the best tool for this task. You might want to use a tokenizer instead. However this *can* be done using a regex, using [recursion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php):

```
$str = "(hello(world)) program";
preg_match_all('/(\(([^()]|(?R))*\))/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Explanation:

```
(          # beginning of capture group 1
  \(       # match a literal (
  (        # beginning of capture group 2
    [^()]  # any character that is not ( or )
    |      # OR
    (?R)   # recurse the entire pattern again
  )*       # end of capture group 2 - repeat zero or more times
  \)       # match a literal )
)          # end of group 1
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/125641)

Comment: Upvote for recursion, bit iffy on the answer because I'm still not sure WTF the OP wants

Comment: The above code returns **duplicates**..You can use `$new_arr = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $matches));` to get rid of the duplicates. @AmalMurali

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: I wonder why that is even necessary? Where does the OP say he wants duplicates to be removed?

Comment: I'm baffled by the downvote; it would be nice for the downvoter to explain why he/she thinks this is an unhelpful and/or incorrect response so I can, perhaps, improve it :)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Why do you think so? I've updated the question to make it more clear. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks @AmalMurali, but I am not sure why but the recursive doesn't work always. If I change the input string to `(hello(world) this is) my first program` , it returns the last character i.e `s`.

Comment: @JeyachandranRathnam: What is the expected output in that case?

Comment: For `(hello(world) this is) my first program` output as
`(hello(world) this is)` and `(world)`

Comment: @JeyachandranRathnam: Do you always want the inner-most element? Or the word enclosed with least number parentheses? Please clarify.

Comment: any value between `(` and `)` , needs to be extracted. as many have suggested before I am not sure if regex is the optimal solution for this.